# How to assign entity Id to another entity without inserting first entity into database in Entity Framework, C#?

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, foreign-keys

Suppose I have 2 tables with many to one relationship: Book -> Author. Author can have multiple books. So, Book entity has Author and AuthorId navigation properties.

For example Author table contains one row: AuthorName. I want to insert new Author only if the name is unique.

So, what I do:

```
var book = new Book();
var authorFromDatabase = getAuthorFromDbByName("author name");
if(authorFromDatabase == null)
{
    // insert new author if it is not already in the database
    book.Author = new Author("author name");
}
else
{
    // how to assign AuthorId to book so that it will not add new Author to the db??
    // the following line inserts new author into the db
    book.AuthorId = authorFromDatabase .AuthorId;
}
```

**So, how can I assign AuthorId to book and not insert a new Author into the db if it's already there?**

Comment: Is it code-first? Are the IDs generated by the DB?

Comment: What about `book.Author = authorFromDatabase;`?

Comment: @sprinter252, it's database first, AuthorId is generated in the database.

Comment: I would go with this:
book.Author = authorFromDatabase ?? new Author("author name");

Comment: So is your problem uniqueness of the name?

Comment: @Alexandre Machado, that was my first attempt, but it will insert new Author every time, event if the author with the same name exists in the db

Comment: @AlekseiChepovoi my best guess is that the method getAuthorFromDbByName is returning null all of the time for some reason. how is the implementation of this method? if the answers below don't help you, you can post it so we can help.

Comment: @Alexandre Machado, that's an examle, I have a db that I populated once and than I need to run this pseudo-code to update the db each time the new data arrives. so, Author table has data in it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting the `.AuthorId` property would not create a new `Author` in the DB - how could it?  You're not actually constructing a new `Author` object and adding it to your `DbContext`.  From what you've given us to look at, it would seem `if(authorFromDatabase == null)` always resolves as `True`.  Have you debugged the code to ensure that the `else` block is ever executed?

You should probably show more of of your code, such as your `Author` and `Book` entity classes as well as your `getAuthorFromDbByName(...)` method implementation and where you instantiate your `DbContext` instances.

Comment: Sorry for misleading you, setting .AuthorId works for me) Just was missing something. Everything works, anyway thanks, after your answer I checked everything again and solved my problem.

Comment: And if(authorFromDatabase == null) not always resolves as True. becuse I already have some entries in the db and I want to update them

Answer (score 0):

If it is about uniqueness I would do something like this:

```
// some code
newBook.Author = CreateOrGetAuthor("The Name");
// more code

private Author CreateOrGetAuthor(string authorName)
{
    var author = _context.Authors.SingleOrDefault(a => a.Name.Equals(authorName, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase));
    if (author == null)
    {
        author = new Author();
        author.Name = authorName;
    }
    return author; 
}
```

Now it depends on if you're using transactions around those both calls. If not, you have to call _context.SaveChanges() first and the return the author in CreateOrGetAuthor. Otherwise it won't have an ID.